# slider pulls to the left as window size decreases to 500px

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Trying to build a wordpress site for our town.  Having some problem with the responsive design.  The page works well until we size the window down to 596px in width. At that point the text on the right starts to take up more vertical space and the slider starts taking up less horizontal space.

Unable to create a working snippet as this is using wordpress plugins but here's a link to the page in question:

https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-story-2/

any help or suggestions as to how to go about fixing this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. Change your `vw` to `%` and then adjust accordingly to your needs. It seems to fix the problem.

```
.os-left {
    margin-top: 1.5%;
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}
.os-right {
    width: 45%;
    margin-right: 1.5%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
}
```

And you also probably don't want your `body` to shift as well, so to fix it use `min-width: 95%` instead of `min-width: 500px`;

```
html, body {
    min-width: 95%;
}
```